# Sharing Specific folder with Two Repositories in Git

Tags: git, git-submodules

Lets say I have a Repository 'Game' which contains a folder 'common', i want to share the common with another Repository 'Puzzle'. One constraint is that i dont want to share Game repository's 'custom' folder with Puzzle.

```
├── Game
│   ├── custom
│   ├── other-folder
│   └── rank
└── Puzzle
    ├── hints
    ├── puzzle-specific-folders
    └── rank
```

- First thing i could think of is using Game as submodule in Puzzle repository Puzzle, but i've to compromise with custom folder.
- Adding New remote in Puzzle repository for Game, but somehow when pulling from Game-remote, is it possible to ignore 'custom' alone? (seems little uncomfortable though)
- Or Something with Branching?
- Whats the best solution and to keep common synchronized acrros both Game and Puzzle?

Comment: leaving a comment for downvote 'll improve the post, also would help me to improve my further questions.

Comment: I dont know why someone might have downvoted you. Take my upvote.

Comment: Can you share the directory tree here. Game, Puzzle, common and game how are they placed...

Comment: Don't overlap git repositories.  Any reason you cannot just have common in its own repository?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It Changes often in common folder, and i want it to be synced in both repositories.

Answer (score 2):

You can use symbolic link of 'common' (origin folder in 'games') in 'puzzle'.
in this way, the 'Puzzle' repository will have only a link and the actual data will be part of 'Games' repository and 'Puzzle' will be always synced to 'Games'

## ln -s /Puzzle/common /Games/common

Comment: I just gave an example for tree, but link wont work because, it goes to different system, someone else also pulls it.